# Java program not working

Tags: java

my java program will not calculate the discounts correctly and I can't figure out why.
I am new to java and I don't know how to fix this so any help would be appreciated.
For example if you buy 100 bags your discount should be 82.50 but mine is saying that it is 27.50

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Coffee {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner bags = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
        System.out.println("Here is the discount list for the IT125 Coffee Company");
        System.out.println("<= 24 Bags      No discount");
        System.out.println(">= 25 Bags      5% ");
        System.out.println(">= 50 Bags      10% ");
        System.out.println(">= 100 Bags     15% ");
        System.out.println(">= 150 Bags     20% ");
        System.out.println(">= 200 Bags     25% ");
        System.out.println(">= 300 Bags     30% ");
        System.out.println("");

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        int num1;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of bags purchased: ");
        num1 = bags.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Bags purchased " + num1);
        double cost, disc, totcost;
        totcost = 0;
        disc = 0;
        cost = num1 * 5.50;
        System.out.println("Normal Price: € " + df.format(cost));



        if (num1 < 25) {
            System.out.println("Your dicount is " + disc);
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 25) {
            disc = cost * 0.05;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 50) {
            disc = cost * 0.1;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 100) {
            disc = cost * 0.15;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 150) {
            disc = cost * 0.2;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 200) {
            disc = cost * 0.25;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));

        }

        else if (num1 >= 300) {
            disc = cost * 0.3;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You should try to shorten your code to a minimal example that reproduces the problem.  Also, show the desired output and the problem output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please try with below code : Added boundary conditions.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Coffee {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner bags = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello and welcome to the program");
        System.out.println("Here is the discount list for the IT125 Coffee Company");
        System.out.println("<= 24 Bags      No discount");
        System.out.println(">= 25 Bags      5% ");
        System.out.println(">= 50 Bags      10% ");
        System.out.println(">= 100 Bags     15% ");
        System.out.println(">= 150 Bags     20% ");
        System.out.println(">= 200 Bags     25% ");
        System.out.println(">= 300 Bags     30% ");
        System.out.println("");

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
        int num1;
        System.out.print("Enter the number of bags purchased: ");
        num1 = bags.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Bags purchased " + num1);
        double cost, disc, totcost;
        totcost = 0;
        disc = 0;
        cost = num1 * 5.50;
        System.out.println("Normal Price: € " + df.format(cost));



        if (num1 < 25) {
            System.out.println("Your dicount is " + disc);
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 25 && num1<50) {
            disc = cost * 0.05;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 50 && num1<100) {
            disc = cost * 0.1;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 100 && num1<150) {
            disc = cost * 0.15;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 150 && num1<200) {
            disc = cost * 0.2;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

        else if (num1 >= 200 && num1<300) {
            disc = cost * 0.25;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));

        }

        else if (num1 >= 300) {
            disc = cost * 0.3;
            totcost = cost - disc;
            System.out.println("Your dicount is € " + df.format(disc));
            System.out.print("Your total cost is € " + df.format(totcost));
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
Hello and welcome to the program
Here is the discount list for the IT125 Coffee Company
<= 24 Bags      No discount
>= 25 Bags      5% 
>= 50 Bags      10% 
>= 100 Bags     15% 
>= 150 Bags     20% 
>= 200 Bags     25% 
>= 300 Bags     30% 

Enter the number of bags purchased: 100
Bags purchased 100
Normal Price: € 550.00
Your dicount is € 82.50
Your total cost is € 467.50
```

Comment: Oh crap I tried to upvote you and now it won't let me change it. Sorry about that...

Answer (score 1):

The root of all evil:

```
 else if (num1 >= 25) {
```

This catches all numbers from 25 to infinity. Use

```
 else if(num1 < 50) {
```

And so on. The last branch will not need a test after you have separated all quantities below 300.

I would like to add that code repetition isn't nice. One way to avoid this is to use

```
int[] limit = new int[]{ 25, 50, 100, 150, 200, 300 };
int[] disct = new int[]{  5, 10,  15,  20, 25,   30 }

int d = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < limit.length; ++i ){ 
    if( qtty < limit[i] ) break;
    d = disct[i];
}

double cost = qtty*price;
double discount = cost*d/100;
totcost = cost - discount;
```

Comment: Either that, or re-order the if statements so that the highest number goes first.

Comment: ... but never a mixture of both.

Answer (score 0):

You have put the `if` blocks in an order such that anything greater than `25` will get caught by the second one even if it is big enough to be caught by one of the later ones. Java doesn't check down the list of `else if`'s; it goes pretty much line by line, so if it sees `350` as an input, it will see that it's greater than `25` and go into that `if` block, even though it could go into a later one. If you reverse the order you have your `if` blocks in, so that the biggest number is checked first, it will work right.

Answer (score -1):

I can see your problem.

It is in your `if`/`else` statements.

Imagine you set num1 to be 60.
You clearly want to execute code C below, but unfortunately, it will execute code B, because it's the first `if` which results in `true`:

Here:

```
   if (num1 < 25) {
     //A
   }
   else if (num1 >= 25) {
     //B
   }
   else if (num1 >= 50) {
     //C
   }
```

The correct `if` block would be:

```
   if (num1 < 25) {
     //A
   }
   else if (num1 >= 25 && num<50) {
     //B
   }
   else if (num1 >= 50) {
     //C
   }
```

This example doesn't have so many conditions as yours does, you need to put in the lower and upper limits into all your `if` statements except for the last one.

Comment: You are just postponing the threshold for error. You can't have `num1 >= 50` without additional precautions...

Comment: I know there are more if blocks, but my explanation is supposed to help the OP understand the problem, not write all their code for them.

Comment: OK, but don't leave misleading code snippets in your answer. You have "correct...would be" heading wrong code, and this is, IMHO, a no-no.